# Android activitiy onclick

Tags: android, onclick

Hi I have implemented this code:

```
        Button goToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg);
    goToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(MindMappingLoginActivity.this, MindMappingRegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Basically splash screen waits 1 second loads a login screen, I have a register button that I would like to use to go to a register activity, now when the splash screen finishes it forces close with unexpected error. Can anyone help or explain please? Thank you.

Problem solved like a fool. I didn't id the correct button my bad its late.

Comment: MindMappingRegisterActivity is your activity class or normal java class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supply the right context

```
MyActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```